# Translate on the horizontal axis the graph of a second degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, parametric

I'm trying to find the parametric second degree polynomial that would allow me to translate the its graph on the horizontal axis. Basically the equivalent of increasing or decreasing `c` in `ax^2 + bx + c` (doing so will translate the graph in the vertical axis). Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: if you have a graph of the form
$$
y= a(x-x_0)^2 +h
$$
then the lowest point (if $a>0$) of the parabola is located at $(x_0, h)$. So basically changing $h$ moves it up and down, and changing $x_0$ moves it left and right.

Comment: Thanks @MattiP., that's exactly what I was looking for. It makes sense: the parameter was "hidden" in x. If you turn that into an answer I'll accept is and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a graph of the form
$$
y= a(x-x_0)^2 + h
$$
then the lowest point (if $a>0$) of the parabola is located at $(x_0, h)$. So basically changing $h$ moves it up and down, and changing $x_0$ moves it left and right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate $f$ with $\alpha$ along the horizontal axis, you want to find what the value $f(x)$ at the point $x + \alpha$, so your translation $\tilde{f}$ must be $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x - \alpha)$.